# Prove that if f is continuous in A then |f| is also continuous.

Tags: calculus

Prove that if $f$ is continuous in *a* then  $|f|$ is also continuous. I have this exercise for homework of calculus I, and I was thinking that it could be treated by cases when $f>0$ and $f<0$, but when I make $f<0$ then it results $-f(a)$, following the continuous definition: $lim_{x\to a} f(x)=f(a)\dots$

Comment: What is $a$, a real number? If so, the usual terminology is "$f$ is continuous **at** $a$."

Comment: Hint: $|\,|a|-|b|\,| \le |a-b|.$

Comment: Well, what is the relationship between $|f(x)-f(a)|$ and $\bigl||f(x)|-|f(a)|\bigr|$? Alternatively, what do you know about the absolute value function?

Comment: @zhw.: That hint is a bit confusing, I think, given the OP.

Comment: My notation was bad; I didn't even see the $a$ in the problem. I should have written $|\,|s|-|t|\,|\le |s-t|.$

Answer (score 2):

There’s no reason to think that $f$ is either always positive or always negative.

HINT: Prove and use the following facts:

- If $f(a)\ne 0$, then there is an $\delta>0$ such that $f(x)$ and $f(a)$ have the same sign whenever $|x-a|<\delta$.
- If $f(a)=0$, $|f(x)-f(a)|=\big||f(x)|-f(a)\big|$ for all $x$.

Comment: Thank you, I get the second point but I don´t understand very well what it follows the first one... could you explain me a little bit more, please?

Comment: @Raquel: It implies that within the interval $(a-\delta,a+\delta)$ the function $|f|$ is either $f$ or $-f$. And continuity at $a$ depends only on what happens inside that interval.